# Indexing / identifying columns adjacent to a column of interest in R dataframe

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to select data/columns adjacent to a particular column. For example, let's say I want to select the two columns to the left and to the right of 'cat_weight'

```
df <- data.frame(dog_height = 1:5,
                 dog_weight = 2:6,
                 cat_height = 3:7,
                 cat_weight = 4:8,
                 bird_height = 5:9,
                 bird_weight = 6:10
)
```

So in this case, that would be 'dog_weight', 'cat_height', 'bird_height', and 'bird_weight'. So far what I've tried is simply creating variables to use as index values based on the index number of the column I'm interested in, e.g.

```
IDvar <- which(colnames(df)=="cat_weight")
IDvar_left_1 <- IDvar-2
IDvar_left_2 <- IDvar-1
IDvar_right_1 <- IDvar+1
IDvar_right_2 <- IDvar+2

cols_left <- df[,IDvar_left_1:IDvar_left_2]
cols_right <- df[,IDvar_right_1:IDvar_right_2]
```

This works but I can't help but think there must be a more elegant solution?

My real data is, of course, much larger and hence would require some more complex indexing (e.g. excluding columns immediately adjacent to the column of interest), so just trying to work out a simple method to apply!

Comment: `IDvar_left <- IDvar-(2:1)`? And the same for the right vars. Or `cols_left <- df[IDvar-(2:1)]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a good idea, here's a solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(dog_height = 1:5,
                 dog_weight = 2:6,
                 cat_height = 3:7,
                 cat_weight = 4:8,
                 bird_height = 5:9,
                 bird_weight = 6:10
)


get_range <- function(central_column,
                      max_range){
  range <- seq(which(colnames(df)==central_column)[[1]]-max_range,
               which(colnames(df)==central_column)[[1]]+max_range)
  
  range[! range %in% which(colnames(df)==central_column)]
}



df |> 
  select(all_of(get_range("cat_weight",2)))
```

Output:

```
  dog_weight cat_height bird_height bird_weight
1          2          3           5           6
2          3          4           6           7
3          4          5           7           8
4          5          6           8           9
5          6          7           9          10
```

Comment: And to remove columns immediately adjacent to the column of interest: `df |> select(-get_range("cat_weight",1))`

Answer (score 2):

Just for variety.

Using base R.

```
myfunc <- function(df, window, column_name){
  
  colInd <- which(colnames(df) %in% column_name)
  
  rng <- range(colInd - window, colInd + window)
  
  subset(df, , ifelse(min(rng) < 1, 1, min(rng)):ifelse(max(rng) > ncol(df), ncol(df), max(rng)))
  
}
```

```
myfunc(data, 3, "cat_weight")

 dog_height dog_weight cat_height cat_weight bird_height bird_weight
1          1          2          3          4           5           6
2          2          3          4          5           6           7
3          3          4          5          6           7           8
4          4          5          6          7           8           9
5          5          6          7          8           9          10
```

***Edit:***

I may have misinterpreted the question. I thought that it included the initial column. Using setdiff, we can remove the column and and get the range to subset

```
myfunc <- function(df, window, column_name){
  
  colInd <- which(colnames(df) %in% column_name)
  
  diff <- setdiff((colInd - window):(colInd + window), colInd)
  
  df[,diff]
}

myfunc(df, 1, "cat_weight")

df[myfunc(df, 1, "cat_weight")]
  cat_height bird_height
1          3           5
2          4           6
3          5           7
4          6           8
5          7           9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution:

After getting the index of the desired column with `which()` we could subset with simple maths:

```
x <- which(colnames(df)=="cat_weight")

df[,c(x-2, x-2, x+1, x+2 )]
```

```
 dog_weight dog_weight.1 bird_height bird_weight
1          2            2           5           6
2          3            3           6           7
3          4            4           7           8
4          5            5           8           9
5          6            6           9          10
```

Comment: I like this! It's similar to my initial solution but using a vector within the index so that you can subtract/add to the initial index variable. Definitely cleaner :)

Answer (score 1):

Anther solution using `data.table` library

```
library(data.table)

i <- which(colnames(df)=="cat_weight")
setDT(df)
df[,(i-2):(i+2)][ , -c("cat_weight")]
```

- output

```
   dog_weight cat_height bird_height bird_weight
1:          2          3           5           6
2:          3          4           6           7
3:          4          5           7           8
4:          5          6           8           9
5:          6          7           9          10
```